# Error al momento de utilizar punteros como vectores dinámicos en C++

Tags: c++, array, punteros, segfault

He estado haciendo un código que me permita utilizar un puntero entero, el cual almacene todos los números enteros que quiera hasta que escriba la palabra "end" y luego los imprima, lo hice de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {

  int *vector;
  int tamanio = 0;
  string comando;
  bool parada = false;

  while(parada != true){
    cout<<"Digite el número de entrada: "; cin>>comando;

    if(comando == "end"){
      parada = true;
      vector=vector-tamanio;
    }
    else{
      *vector = stoi(comando);
      vector++;
      tamanio++;
    } 
  }

  for(int i=0; i<tamanio; i++){
    cout<<*vector<<" ";
    vector++;
  }

  vector = vector - tamanio; // Para que vuelva a "[0]"
  return 0;
}
```

Funciona correctamente, el problema está que cuando quiero implementar otro código exactamente igual, pero con variables diferentes, me genera error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  
  int *vector;
  int tamanio = 0;
  string comando;
  bool parada = false;

  while(parada != true){
    cout<<"Digite el número de entrada: "; cin>>comando;

    if(comando == "end"){
      parada = true;
      vector=vector-tamanio;
    }
    else{
      *vector = stoi(comando);
      vector++;
      tamanio++;
    } 
  }

  for(int i=0; i<tamanio; i++){
    cout<<*vector<<" ";
    vector++;
  }

  vector = vector - tamanio; // Para que vuelva a "[0]"
  
  
  cout<<endl<<endl<<"cambio"<<endl<<endl;
  //////////////////////////////////////


  int *orden;
  int tamanioOrden = 0;
  string comando2;
  bool paradaOrden = false;
  

  while(paradaOrden != true){
    cout<<"Digite la posición que quiere que salga: "; cin>>comando2;

    if(comando2 == "end"){
      paradaOrden = true;
      orden=orden-tamanioOrden;
    }
    
    else{
      *orden = stoi(comando2);
      orden++;
      tamanioOrden++;
    } 
    
  }
  
  for(int i=0; i<tamanioOrden; i++){
    cout<<*orden<<" ";
    orden++;
  }

  return 0; 
}
```

La primera parte funciona bien, pero luego en la segunda, apenas ingreso el primer valor genera un error, como se muestra en la siguiente image:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo extraño es que cuando quito la primera parte (la que va antes de la impresión en consola de "cambio") funciona igualmente bien, ¿por qué sucede eso, y cómo podría corregirlo para que me permita implementar los 2 códigos a la vez?

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, lo que estas haciendo esta fundamentalmente mal, y puede pasar cualquier cosa ya que es comportamiento indefinido.

Creas un puntero:

```
  int *vector;
```

Y nunca lo apuntas a una dirección de memoria valida. Tu ordenador no es magia, y no le va a dar memoria si tu no se lo dices.

Yo ya consideraria un milagro que el primer codigo corriera. En mi maquina no corrio, el compilador le dio de un solo el valor de `nullptr`. El segmentation fault se da cuando tocas memoria que no es tuya. Que es lo que haces con ese puntero.

La solucion seria esta:

1. Le asignas memoria al puntero usando `new`
2. Usas el `std::vector`, que seria lo mejor, estas en c++ por algo

#### Nota

Añadele a los flags de clang lo siguiente:

```
-fsanitize=address -O2
```

Asi te avisara cuando toques memoria que no te toca, y no entraras en comportamiento indefinido.

Eso si, solo usalo cuando estes probando la app, que la realentiza, y eso en produccion no sirve.

Tambien te serviria añadir:

```
-Wall -Wextra -Werror
```

Para que te avise en tiempo de compilacion algunos de tus errores.